# connect: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: go, redis

When i try to make multiple (hundreds) connections to redis unix socket, i get this error.
It is result of Dial call.
What's causing it? Is that redis denies or some OS imposed limits?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sync"
  "flag"
  "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

func client(num int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  defer wg.Done()
  red, err := redis.Dial("unix", "/tmp/redis.sock")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(num, "Dial", err)
    return
  }

  defer red.Close()

  _, err = red.Do("SELECT", 0)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(num, "SELECT", err)
    return
  }

  _, err = red.Do("GET", "redplaytest")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(num, "GET", err)
    return
  }
}

func main() {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup

  var count int

  flag.IntVar(&count, "n", 1000, "number")
  flag.Parse()

  for i:= 0; i < count; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go client(i, &wg)
  }

  wg.Wait()
  fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

This is what happens, number of fails vary from launch to launch:

```
$ ./redplay -n 800
693 Dial dial unix /tmp/redis.sock: connect: resource temporarily unavailable
509 Dial dial unix /tmp/redis.sock: connect: resource temporarily unavailable
217 Dial dial unix /tmp/redis.sock: connect: resource temporarily unavailable
594 Dial dial unix /tmp/redis.sock: connect: resource temporarily unavailable
436 Dial dial unix /tmp/redis.sock: connect: resource temporarily unavailable
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that redis connect queue gets full and i have to wait and try again later.
This is how i managed to make it work:

```
...
tries := 10
for tries != 0 {
  red, err = redis.Dial(red_sock_type, red_sock)
  if err == nil {
    break
  }
  if nerr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && nerr.Temporary() {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1000)) * time.Millisecond)
  } else {
    break
  }
  tries--
}
...
```